# How to add Google Play tab and iBookStore tab on facebook?

Tags: apple-books, google-play-books

Welcome,
I'm an self-publishing author and i was wondering if i can by any means add a clear and visible link to my GooglePlay/iBookStore author profile on facebook. I've already tried adding an facebook app and bind it to my tabs section, but after click it displays nothing but a blank facebook page. Any suggestions or help?

Thanks in advance.